# Slice data in Power BI based on multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data table in this format, with four possible states for a number of machines:

```
MachineID...IsActive...NeedsRefill...ServedCustomers
0           FALSE      FALSE         1239
0           FALSE      TRUE          1248
0           TRUE       FALSE         4782
0           TRUE       TRUE          8176
1           FALSE      FALSE         1239
1           FALSE      TRUE          1248
1           TRUE       FALSE         4782
1           TRUE       TRUE          8176
...
```

I'd like to display a graph of the ServedCustomers value based on what the state is of the machines. I'd like this to be done through a simple slicer:

```
Machines are active  {X}/{ }
Machines need refill {X}/{ }
```

And filter the data based on what boxes in the slicer are selected. I've been struggling to find a way using DAX to filter based on multiple column values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Step1 Please create these two calculate **Measure**

**Machines are active = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Table1[IsActive]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[IsActive]=TRUE()))**

**Machines need refill = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Table1[NeedsRefill]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[NeedsRefill]=TRUE()))**

[image]

[Download PowerBI file used in above example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwo0JwrOBlWjREVfUV9rRlBXdE0/view?usp=sharing)

Hoping this will help

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not sure, however, that this does what I am after. I have 2 unique machines, which both have 4 possible states based on two booleans which should be in the slicer. I only want to show the data for one of the states of each machine based on which of the slicer checkboxes are currently ticked.